Calling Predefined Parameterised Query in vb.net through ODBC
I Have a Parametrised query In Access 2016
I Want To call That Query In Vb.NET
What Is The Method To Call That Parametrised Query In VB.Net ?
Predefined Access Query With Name qrySumOfSQty Is
  PARAMETERS S_StartDate DateTime, S_EndDate DateTime;
  SELECT tblSale.SaleDate, tblSaleDetail.ProductId, Sum(tblSaleDetail.Quantity) AS SLQty
  FROM tblSaleDetail INNER JOIN tblSale ON tblSaleDetail.SaleId = tblSale.SaleId
  GROUP BY tblSale.SaleDate, tblSaleDetail.ProductId
  HAVING (((tblSale.SaleDate) Between [S_StartDate] And [S_EndDate]))
  ORDER BY tblSaleDetail.ProductId;

and Calling It Through VB>Net Is
  strQuery = "Select * From qrySumOfSQty"

  cmdDesign.Connection = connection
  cmdDesign.CommandText = strQuery
  cmdDesign.Parameters.AddWithValue("S_StartDate", DateFrom.Value)
  cmdDesign.Parameters.AddWithValue("S_EndDate", DateTo.Value)
  dtReader = cmdDesign.ExecuteReader

It Gives Error
  ERROR [07002] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 2.


You should avoid using AddWithValue add parameters. It will work in most cases but it infers the data type and sometimes it will get it wrong. So you don't have to worry about  which ones will work and which won't, just don't us it at all. Always use Add and specify the data type explicitly, e.g. cmdDesign.Parameters.Add("S_StartDate", OdbcType.Date).Value = DateFrom.Value.

You're not calling that query from VB.NET, as it stands. You're executing an inline query in VB.NET and that query is executing your inbuilt query without passing it any parameters. If you want to execute the inbuilt query directly then you have to treat it like a stored procedure. You need to set the CommandType property of your command to StoredProcedure instead of the default Text and then you set the CommandText to just the name of the query.
strQuery = "qrySumOfSQty"

cmdDesign.Connection = connection
cmdDesign.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmdDesign.CommandText = strQuery

